# How can I make my ListView in flutter scrollable?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, listview, cross-platform

I am new to flutter. I am trying to build a card app and I have a ListView for the suites of each card. I just realized that when I flip the screen to landscape mode, I get a overflow error. I figured it would be fine because I have a ListView. But nope. So I flipped it back to portrait and added some HUGE text to see if that would scroll and to my suprise it did not.

I did some research and added `physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),` but still not working. All help is appreciated!

```
ListView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
  physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  shrinkWrap: true,
  children: [
    for (var item in suites)
      Text('test', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 100.0),),
    for (var item in suites)
      FlatButton(
        onPressed: () {
          var suiteId = item.suiteId;
          var suite = item.suite;
          var suiteImage = item.suiteImage;
          var suiteColor = item.suiteColor;

          print(suiteColor);

          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => SuiteScreen(
                suiteId: suiteId,
                suite: suite,
                suiteImage: suiteImage,
                suiteColor: suiteColor,
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
        child: ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.deck),
          title: Text(
            item.suite,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 30.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
  ],
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was sooooo simple! Just wrap my container which was calling the listview with a Expanded widget!

Answer (score 1):

just wrap your listview with the SingleChildScrollView widget and it'll work fine after that. You can copy paste the below code.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  child: ListView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
  physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  shrinkWrap: true,
  children: [
    for (var item in suites)
      Text('test', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 100.0),),
    for (var item in suites)
      FlatButton(
        onPressed: () {
          var suiteId = item.suiteId;
          var suite = item.suite;
          var suiteImage = item.suiteImage;
          var suiteColor = item.suiteColor;

          print(suiteColor);

          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => SuiteScreen(
                suiteId: suiteId,
                suite: suite,
                suiteImage: suiteImage,
                suiteColor: suiteColor,
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
        child: ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.deck),
          title: Text(
            item.suite,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 30.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

You can implement scrollable row in flutter using the below code

and for scrollable column just change Column with Row

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  child: Row(
   children: <Widget>[
     Text('hi'),
     Text('hi'),
     Text('hi'),
   ]
  )
)
```